# Paypal checkout javascript integration Debit and credit card option not work

Tags: javascript, paypal

I want to create PayPal payment using javascript SDK. I have followed PayPal documentation https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference/. Below is the code that I have implemented. The code is working for PayPal payment but when clicking in "Debit or Credit Card", and filling all the billing information, it's not working. When I looked into network request, to URL(https://www.paypal.com/graphql?fetch_credit_form_submit) and it's showing 429 HTTP code with no any response. I have looked lot of videos where this code is working but its not working for me. Any help is really appreciated.

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQTjGimz0db5Gqx2NLBvgXfc-dckdeKGJzJ5KY1JBsv7K5OWYsjipJuh8MX25IoohCWNl09RL4hA24uN"></script> 
 <script>
 paypal.Buttons({
  createOrder:function(data,actions){
   return actions.order.create({
  purchase_units:[{
   amount:{
    value:'40.99'
   }
  }]
 })
}
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Comment: https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/why-did-i-get-http-error-code-429-ts2115

Answer (score -2):

```
 <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AQTjGimz0db5Gqx2NLBvgXfc-dckdeKGJzJ5KY1JBsv7K5OWYsjipJuh8MX25IoohCWNl09RL4hA24uN"></script>   

<script>
 paypal.Buttons({

      createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            // Set up the transaction
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                  value: 49.0
                }
              }]
            });
          },
          onApprove: function(data, actions) {
           ///.........
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).